# invalid input syntax for type double precision: " chargebackvalue"

Tags: sql, postgresql, double, precision

I'm trying to upload a .csv file to Postgres and I'm getting this error:

> invalid input syntax for type double precision: " chargebackvalue"

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWHvq.png)

Here it is the structure of the table:
[table structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU8ax.png)

The code of the .csv file:

```
stoneid; mundipaggid; cardnumber; emblem; chargebackvalue; cardmask; chargebackdate; emitter; description; purchasedate; clientName; tacomorderid; useremail
0155477; 'or_3E2W0X5s5jtPjWYO';0670000546857; 'Visa'; 60.6; '498453******3271'; '2019-10-17'; 'Banco do Brasil S.A.'; 'Teste'; '2019-10-10'; 'Silvana Teixeira Da Silva';99854; 'teste@teste.com'
```

Comment: Looks like it is trying to process the line with the headers as if they were data.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I would recommend loading the data into a staging table, where all the columns are strings.

Then, select from that table to load the final table.  This makes it easier to track down problems in the data that might occur during the load.

Clearly the row you have shown is not the cause of the error.  Or, if this is the entire file, then you simply have not skipped the first line because it has header names rather than values.